# Ansible get hostnames from one group as a variable to another play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Here is inventory file.

```
[abc]
host1
host2

[123]
host3
```

And main.yml

```
#play1
- hosts: abc
  roles:
    - { role: abc }
  tasks: 
    ...
#play2
- hosts: 123
  roles:
    - { role: 123 }
  tasks:
    debug: msg="{{inventory_hostname}}"
```

Basically I need to run some commands in host3 and the commands need host1 and host2 in it. So how can I get host1 and host2 which are in group abc into play2 `debug: msg="{{inventory_hostname}}"`, I know  inventory_hostname is getting host3. is there any other way I can get only host1 and host2. Let me know if I'm not clear.

Thanks in Advance.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "groups" magic variable as discussed in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables).

> groups is a list of all the groups (and hosts) in the inventory. This can be used to enumerate all hosts within a group.

So you can reference, e.g., `groups['abc']` or `groups['abc'][0]`.

Comment: Thank you, they worked. I also looped  "groups" magic variable and working like charm

Comment: Is there a way I can use OR operation in groups magic variable like `with_items: {{ groups['123'] }} or {{ groups['234'] }}`

Comment: What is your intent? Do you want to combine both groups, or use `groups['234']` if there are no hosts in `groups['123']`?

Comment: so there are 2 environments and the script creates hosts file with what ever env the server falls in, like env1 is group['123']and env2 group['234']. they can be group [123] or [234] in the host file and when Im looping hosts from the whatever group exists in host file 

```.    - debug:
        msg: "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{ groups['123'] }} or {{ groups['234'] }}"```

Comment: There's nothing really special about the groups variable. Treat it like any other variable. For instance, you could do `{{ groups['123'] | default(groups['234']) }}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one line solution:

```
- name: Print hostnames of 'registry' inventory group
  vars:
    registry_hostnames: "{{ groups['registry'] | map('extract', hostvars) | map(attribute='ansible_host') }}"
  debug:
    var: registry_hostnames
```

It uses the inventory names listed in `groups` variable to access the `hostvars` variable (with the inventory names as indices).
From the resulting list we can use another map to access the inventory variable that we're interested in.